# RecyclerView within NestedScrollView Layout Not Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have some problem with scrolling in RecyclerView within a NestedScrollView, beside CollapsingToolbarLayout.
The Problem is RecyclerView Does not Scroll and CollapsingToolbarLayout Does not Expand/Collapse. 
Here is the XML:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/trans"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header_basij" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="1000"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="2000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/pbar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/trans"
                android:src="@drawable/loader"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/interneterror"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorhandler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="خطا در اتصال به اینترنت"
                    android:textColor="#212121" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tryagainme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="سعی دوباره"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_icon_tint_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text_color"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks For Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call "`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`"

Comment: @Ram `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` can only work in api level 21 and above. therefore not solution for lower apis

Comment: `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `NestedScrollView` does not call AppBarLayout.Behavour class when it receive scroll events from recyclerview. that is, when a scroll happens in recyclerview, recyclerview dispatches/passes the scroll progress to `NestedScrollView`. `NestedScrollView` receives the scroll event but does nothing with it.

**Inside nestedscrollview class**

```
@Override
public void onNestedpreScroll(View target,int dx, int dy, int[] consumed){
         //Do nothing
}
```

To overcome this and make appbarlayout expand/collapse when scrolling recyclerview, just create a custom class that extends NestedScrollView and overide the above method and call method `dispatchNestedPreScroll()` which informs the appbarlayout of the scroll event and make it respond to it.

```
  public class CustomNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView{

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

  @Override
  public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed){
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx,dy,consumed,null);
  }
}
```

And then use this class in your layout.xml

```
<com.my.package.CustomNestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   /*
       CONTENT
   */

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This did not work for me!!
This is complex (at least for me)
Also this seems to be a bit of overcoding. I solved this without doing all this..
I encourage you n readers to find easier ways. Because there are!