# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-design-library, nestedscrollview

Iam trying to place a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. The problem is that if I place the RecyclerView inside a horizontal LinearLayout, the recycler view shows. But if I place it into Vertical LinearLayout it doesnot show up. Here is something that I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/AppBrightRed"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_appicon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:hint="LOCATION"
                    android:id="@+id/ATView" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Checkin"
                    android:textColor="@color/AppBackground"
                    android:id="@+id/btnCheckin"
                    android:background="@color/AppBrightRed" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ----DOES NOT SHOW IF PLACED HERE
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
              </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Change `layout_height` of recyclerview's parent linear layout to `match_parent`

Comment: @Apurva thanks for the reply. but that doesn't work either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: Please avoid using recyclerView inside Scroll View. If you gonna make it work by somehow, it still be problem for future and for app scrolling performance. Android strongly discard this type of design.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `LinearLayout` instead of `NestedScrollView`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Huh. This works. I used a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` and it *also* worked! Note that I programatically call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)` on the `RecyclerView`. Weird, I didn't think collapsing/scrolling would still work, but it did!! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at : [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

By the way, it won't work i've tried everything you can even imagine it.

But, you have these options:

**1.** Using a Library like
    https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager

**2.** Or, implementing your own custom `LinearLayoutManager`

**3.**  or Using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
        on both.(perhaps it will works)

And of coure, you could use that inside `CoordinatorLayout` and outside the `NestedScrollView`.

**Check this answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951558/4409113