# android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView height issue

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have the listView in the NestedScrollView since the nested scrollView are out of the screen so some list will not be shown

[image]

Comment: What's the sense of putting a ListView inside a ScrollView?

Comment: I want to scroll if there are many lists, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You should probably avoid putting multiple ListViews on a single screen.

Comment: Combine data from `many lists` and use this data for one recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. And wrap it with custom LinearLayoutManager. 
[How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview/32736113#32736113)

Answer (score 0):

For the fast fix just put it in linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
                    android:id="@+id/listViewTaskInComplete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` + `ListView` != View with nested scrolling available, is it?

Comment: yes, and since I have implemented on listView so this is the easiest solution  right now. However, if I have time I will study on RecycleView