# Recyclerview inside nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I have a layout which is like this

TextView 1

TextView 2

TextView 3

ImageView

Recyclerview

[item 1 to 10
organized vertically]

Now, when I am scrolling the page, the entire page must scroll, not the Recyclerview alone. 
This is a very common and an old thing in android, the solutions I get is implementing the
[Is there an addHeaderView equivalent for RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview?lq=1)

I don't want to follow this approach as it is quite a hacky solution. I feel implementing recyclerview inside nestedscrollview might solve my issue, am I taking the right approach? or should I be using coordinator layout?
Any help is highly appreciated, can you also provide me some links that meet my requirements.?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: @akash89 facing same issue...have you got any solution?

Comment: @Neo. check out the answer, see if you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution for this query. Have a look at this layout,
The idea is to have a

CoordinatorLayout as the root

--AppBar layout happens to be the direct child layout for Coordinator

Host the relative layout that will have the different textview/radiobutton (that you want to add as a header kind of thing)

---Close the appbarlayout

Add the recyclerview just below the appbarlayout.

It will work fine, check out the layout that I have used and don't forget to add app:behavior in proper places.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New RadioButton"
                        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
             android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout"
             android:id="@+id/recyclerview_settings_list"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```