# NestedScrollView and RecyclerView issues, how to separate them?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I'm not sure how to implement this.. I want to use:

1. Collapsing Toolbar
2. "normal" Layout (NestedScrollView)
3. RecyclerView
4. **and** navigate by the NavigationDrawer (so the layouts come together in my activity_main.xml)

The issues comes up when I try to use the RecyclerView - because of the NestedScrollView (yeah, the rule "don't place multiple scrollables together" is true)...

But how to achieve this? Is there a possibility to keep the layouts separated in some way?

*Info*: I am replacing the content of the app in the FrameLayout (see middle section).

Would it be a proper solution to insert multiple NestedScrollViews (in each Fragment one, which should be scrollable)?

Here is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@color/main_frame"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_overlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            >
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryNavDrawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_items"
    />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve this is to use only a `RecyclerView` with an adapter handling different view types.
For the first adapter position, the list item will be your fixed content once in `NestedScrollView`, and for other positions what you want to use is the `RecyclerView` items from your current solution.