# How to make an Activity which is vertical scrollable but has specific elements that are horizontal scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm trying to make an activity which works similar to this one from the Google Play Store.(https://vid.me/zfnV)

I tried it with a NestedScrollView in which I had a Textview and other things like a button. The vertical scrolling for this works fine. Now I would like to have some Cardviews which are horizontal scrollable in the same activity.

Any suggestions or tips about how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this

put a RecyclerView with `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` as parameter for the element you want to scroll horizontally

as parent of **RecyclerView** put **NestedScrollView**

[image]

not that we should never put a scrollable view inside a scrollable view unless we set the height of the second scrollable view which is your RecyclerView

see this post it will help you implementing this solution :

note that 
[How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Good luck

Comment: thanks a lot it worked! :)
I even tried it with a GridLayoutManager instead of a LinearLayoutManager so that I have 3 columns with cards. like when you press the more button in Google Play to see all cards.