# Android CollapsingToolbar with viewPager and RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar with ViewPager inside it. ViewPager has 3 fragments, one of which has a RecyclerView inside it. ColllapsingToolbar works fine for the other two fragments but it doesn't work as expected in the fragment with RecyclerView.

I am using recyclerview version v7 23.2.1. My recylcerView has custom items (each item contains a parent cardview).

I have seen other posts related to this issue but none of them were of great help.

My Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:background="@color/color_ee"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/topSubmissionsList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My RecyclerView Item code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:background="@color/color_ee"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dip">

<!-- My Custom Content -->

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview/32736113#32736113

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and comment further.

Comment: can you show you screen and explain exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the layout in `NestedScrollView` which you are inflating inside `RecylcerView`. I mean your `CardView`.

It should look like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dip">

<!-- My Custom Content -->

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**UPDATE:**

Your `RecyclerView` should be like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

the key thing here is `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` it will make your scrolling fine.

Comment: My initial layout was exactly same as you suggested. But it didn't work.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else, I use `CardView` alot and this is how i use it

Comment: I have another nested RecyclerView in my item layout. Is that a problem?