# Horizontal RecyclerView inside ScrollView not inflating - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-adapter

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView` but none of the adapter methods are being triggered.

This is my fragment with the `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/selector"/>

  .....
  .....

   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my selector.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="@color/green">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rv_kids"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here I'm setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView`:

```
selectorAdapter = new selectorAdapter(activity, kids);
rv_items.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
rv_items.setAdapter(selectorAdapter);
selectorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The thing is, the green background I've set to the selector shows up but none of the adapter methods are triggered and the `RecyclerView` doesn't inflate. 
What can I do differently?

Comment: use nested scrollview

Comment: Move the setlayoutmanager line top of the setadapter

Comment: @Nithinlal hey that's where it was before and it didn't work even then, so I had tried moving it below just to try.

Comment: First remove the RelativeLayout from scroll view and check its is showing now

Comment: @Nithinlal ScrollView can only host one direct child and I have other elements apart from the RecyclerView which is why the enclosing RelativeLayout

Comment: @Mallika you have to position the recyclerview in your RelativeLayout or try using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You should use Nested Scrollview 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html instead. However you may need to write your own LayoutManager. Check out this SO Answer for more details

[How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview/32736113#32736113)

Comment: Hey the custom LayoutManager was crashing at `View view =  recycler.getViewForPosition(position)` even though I was binding the data with the list correctly and the adapter count was correct. But instead of debugging further, I think I'm gonna switch to using a LinearLayout and add views to it instead and make it behave like a RecylerView.