# recyclerview scroll to top after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have very strange problem and I tried to resolve it about 2 days. I have a `RecyclerView` which nested in the `NestedScrollView`. I create `EndlessScrollListener` for my `NestedScrollView` and it load more data correctly, but when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeChanged()` my list scroll to top to the second item or another. Also when I want an update all items in my `SwipeRefreshLayout` it maybe mixed(for example the image from fourth item maybe set in first item and etc). This happens only when I want to update items, when I open my app first time everything is ok.  I have no idea why it happens, please help me. Thanks in advance. My code
It's my function for initialize the adapter

```
private void setFeedRecycler(RecyclerView feedRecyclerView, List<Edge<Activity>> feeds){
    noFeedsTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    feedsArray.addAll(feeds);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    feedRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    feedRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    feedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    feedsDashboardAdapter = new FeedsDashboardAdapter(getActivity(), this, feedsArray, feedRecyclerView, mainDashboardLayout);
    feedsDashboardAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(loadMoreListenerFeeds);
    feedRecyclerView.setAdapter(feedsDashboardAdapter);
}
```

After get data from server I update my adapter from the main UI

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           feedsArray.addAll(feedMobile.getEdges());
           feedsDashboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}});
```

When I want to update my all items

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener refreshListener = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        loadAfterCursorFeed = "";
        feedsArray.clear();
        getUserFeeds(user.getAccessToken(), user.getClientId(), loadAfterCursorFeed);
    }
};
```

loadAfterCursorFeed it's like an id for the next page of a data.
And finally my adapter

```
    public FeedsDashboardAdapter(Context context, DashboardFragment fragment, ArrayList<Edge<Activity>> feeds, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     NestedScrollView mainDashboardLayout){
            this.feeds = feeds;
            this.context = context;
            this.fragment = fragment;
            this.mainDashboardLayout = mainDashboardLayout;
            this.linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            this.client = new RestClient().getApiService();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            user = new Gson().fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("user", null), User.class );
            mainDashboardLayout.setOnScrollChangeListener(new EndlessParentScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "page " + page + " totalItemsCount " + totalItemsCount);
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_USER_FEEDS) {
                View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user_feed, parent, false);
                return new CategoryUserFeedHolder(layoutView, context);
            } else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_SHARE_EVENT) {
                View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_feed_shared_event, parent, false);
                return new CategoryShareEventHolder(layoutView);
            }  else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
                View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loading_item_layout, parent, false);
                return new LoadingViewHolder(layoutView);
            }
            return null;
        }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof CategoryShareEventHolder) {
    //set necessary field
    }
    else if(holder instanceof CategoryUserFeedHolder){
    //set necessary field
    }
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.feeds ==null ? 0 : this.feeds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (feeds.get(position) == null)
            return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
        else if (feeds.get(position).getResponse().getEvent() != null)
            return VIEW_TYPE_SHARE_EVENT;
        return VIEW_TYPE_USER_FEEDS;
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener listener){
        this.onLoadMoreListener = listener;
    }
```

Comment: any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

Try using RecyclerView without NestedScrollView in your layout, look at this answer
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31818632/6926324

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of just adding link, add some relevant code from the other answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20173262).