# How to make RecyclerView do recycling inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, optimization, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, recycle

I tried to put several views, including `RecyclerView`, into a `NestedScrollView`. I used `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` and it looked nice for small data sets but started to be laggy for bigger ones.

After spending some time on logging the `onCreateViewHolder()` method I understood that the recycler view creates them all at once as the old `ListView`. I tried to find reasons of such behavior in `RecyclerView` docs, but I found it in `ScrollView` [description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
>   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
>   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
>   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
>   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
>   ScrollView.

I hoped that `NestedScrollView` would solve the issue but it appears that it hadn't.

Are there any ways, for example, using some custom `LayoutManager` to use `RecyclerView` with its optimizations of view recycling?

P.s. Of course, I know about method `getItemViewType(int pos)` and possibility to add custom headers and footers using this technique but it looks like an ugly workaround for me. And yes, I am using it at the moment, because it is better to have code that is harder to maintain than such big performance issue.

Comment: try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview

Comment: @Gaket Have you solved this issue? I'm also having the same problem

Comment: Hey! Have u found a solution for this?

Comment: @Gaket did you find any ways to recycle items under nested scrollview

Comment: My research has shown there is no easy way. at least in 2021. I'm working on a custom layout manager that may be able to resolve the issue, not sure if it will be good to be open sourced though.

Comment: So, if you need to do smth like this - your best solution is to use Concat Adapters, different item types or Coordinator / Motion layout to achieve the desired behavior.