# Unable to scroll LinearLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I want to make a layout that display several items, but I cannot make them fully unfold, so I use a ScrollView. However, I find that I can only scroll the first GridView, the last two item can not be scroll up.
What I need is to display two GridView fully and all items can be scrolled，but I do not know how to deal with the problem.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ifchan.reader.AllClassActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/all_class_tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        app:title="All Class"
        app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/all_class_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/all_class_tool_bar"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/all_class_male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="male"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/all_class_male_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/all_class_female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="female"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/all_class_female_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use Recycler View or a non scrollable gridview if you want to use scrollview.

    public class NonScrollGridView extends GridView{

        public NonScrollGridView (Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        public NonScrollGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        public NonScrollGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }
        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }



     <NonScrollGridView 
                    android:id="@+id/all_class_female_grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put **GridView**s into `ScrollView`. It will not work as you expected.

Try Using `GridLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView` and put it in `NestedScrollView`

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview) question for detailed explanations.

If you want to use GridView anyway, you can use this [ExpandableHeightGridView](https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765) 
 which extends GridView

Comment: I just want to fully display all items in two GridView, can I make it simpler?

Comment: @IfChan updated my answer and added GridView option for you.