# Nested recyclerviews inside nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement nested `RecyclerView`. I did that but parent `RecyclerView` scroll was not smooth on scroll. I did alot of optimization, but still didn't manage to be successful with scroll till I though of putting parent recyclerview inside `NestedScrollView`. Scroll is flawless now, but I've a problem.

**If I scroll (even tiny bit) my inner `RecyclerView` (horizontal), I immediately get back to the start [of vertical recyclerview - parent]**.

This happens one time. Why is that and is it possible to fix it?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parent_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: **`RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`**

Comment: @NileshRathod I've `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on parent recyclerview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview

Comment: `If I scroll till the end of my inner RecyclerView (horizontal), I immediately get back to the start.` - Start of your horizontal `RecyclerView` or parent `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Does the horizontal `RecyclerView` loads new data when it reaches to the end of scrolling?

Comment: use this ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);

Comment: @ReazMurshed Yes, it does. Also, it goes to start of vertical recyclerview not horizontal, my bad. I need solution for API 19+. :)

Comment: What about the horizontal `RecyclerView`? Does it stay in the position where it gets updated? Or, it does also scroll back to the first position??

Comment: @ReazMurshed It looks like it stays where it gets updated.

Comment: Please check the answer. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your problem, you parent `RecyclerView` gets updated and scrolls to position 0 when the inner horizontal `RecyclerView` items get updated. You have also stated that the horizontal `RecyclerView` stays in the same place update the items are updated. In this case, you need to save the state of the parent `RecyclerView` and then put it back where it was after the items in your horizontal `RecyclerView` get updated.

```
// Save state
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
recyclerViewState = parentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();

// Restore state
parentRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```

Save the state before you call the API for updating the data in your horizontal `RecyclerView` and then restore the position of the parent `RecyclerView` when the update finishes.

Comment: Is there an option to do achieve result by xml attributes or in more elegant manner? Also, I'd like to point out, that I don't really have to scroll till last element (when new ones get loaded), I can do tiny scroll and the hop to start will happen. :/

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Oh, I see. Please edit your question and add the comments in your question, those were asked for clarification so that other people can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.
Basically, what I did was wrap recycler view inside of relative layout and set `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and now it works good.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/parent_rv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```