# ConstraintLayout (with RecyclerView ) inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a structure like this when I try to **scroll outside area of RecyclerView** its not working (scrolling)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView     
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help on this !!!

Comment: hope this help you https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview

Comment: Will try n tell you

Comment: Any solution for this? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

NestedScrollView  wrap 
constraintlayout wrap

RecyclerView wrap

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this property for `RecyclerView` - `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`