# Scroll behaviour of AndroidX RecyclerView view with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, nestedscrollview

I'm migrating my application from appcompat to AndroidX. Everything works except that I am not able to set one scroll for both `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` and 
 `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.

I have tried adding

```xml
setHasFixedSize(true)
setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

but it's not working. My XML now looks this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/itenarydays"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@drawable/roundshape"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/textsise10">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sketch" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:animationCache="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:id="@+id/list_daycount"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="none"

            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@drawable/shape_redround"
            android:id="@+id/framelyt_add"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/textsise10">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Don't put RecyclerView inside another scrolling view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: was working in app-compat, not in androidx

Comment: @EugenPechanec you can definitely have recyclerviews in other scrolling views if nested scrolling is disabled on the RV.

Comment: @BrandonMcAnsh I was rather concerned about the recycling aspect of a RecyclerView. ScrollView doesn't recycle its contents. If you put a vertical wrap_content RV in a vertical SV there will be no recycling. The whole view hierarchy will be in memory at all times. A better idea would be to adapt the whole view hierarchy into different item types of a single vertical RV.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

instead of this:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the value of the string resource.

Comment: they changed the scrolling behavior and putted it a private package so you have to access it by "$" , for me it works this way as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to remove the `layout_behavior` attribute from the RecyclerView since you have nested scrolling disabled for it (and already have it set for the NestedScrollView)