# Auto scroll to specific recycler view wrapped inside nested scrollview seems to be not working for Android X

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx, autoscroll, android-nestedscrollview

For my app, I'm using Recycler view (androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView) wrapped inside NestedScrollView (androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView) as apart from listview data, I wanted to show few more individual data elements.

Scrolling is working fine, but autoscrolling recycler view to some specific index position is not at all happening.

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView> 
    <LinearLayout> 
     <View/> //some more views 
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/> 
    </LinearLayout> 
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Also, tried using the below-

```
    recyclerList.apply 
    { 
    recyclerList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
recyclerList.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false 
val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(context,dataList) 
recyclerList.adapter = adapter recyclerList.smoothScrollToPosition(dataList.size() - 1)//auto scroll to the bottom 
    }
```

The above code snippet is not autoscrolling the recycler view to the last item of the list. Please suggest.

Already tried answers -

1. [How to fix the scroll behaviour of Android androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView view with androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573167/how-to-fix-the-scroll-behaviour-of-android-androidx-recyclerview-widget-recycler)
2. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView/issues/27

Comment: Use in _run()_ method of recyclerview using `recyclerList.post(){....`

Comment: @Piyush are you suggesting to use something like this? -  recyclerList.post{ recyclerList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
recyclerList.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false 
val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(context,dataList) 
recyclerList.adapter = adapter recyclerList.smoothScrollToPosition(dataList.size() - 1)}

Comment: Yes. But not whole part . Only _recyclerList.smoothScrollToPosition(dataList.size() - 1)_ snippet

Comment: tried the same, but this also seems be to not autoscrolling the list as expected.