# Recycler with Gridlayout manager inside NestedScrollView not scrolling Properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-xml, android-nestedscrollview

I have an NestedScrollView and inside that a parent linear layout which contains a recyclerview as well.

Here's my XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_alpha_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Welcome"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="Hi User" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logout" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/versionCode"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:text="v1.5" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newheader"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/news_feed"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/refereshBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_refresh"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Refresh"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_selector"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newFeedNoDataTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:text="No Data Found"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/newFeedRv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/newsfeed_items" />


                <com.github.demono.AutoScrollViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:stopWhenTouch="false" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <!-- <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/menu"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/serviceRv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                    app:spanCount="2"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/services_item" />


                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/knowledgeShareCardView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_alpha_knowledgeshare"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/serviceTitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Knowledge Share"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/serviceSubTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
                            tools:text="Administrator" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">


    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried setting ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(serviceRv, false), but this did not worked and also I tried putting my parent linear inside a scrollview keeping its nestedScroll = false.
Can any one suggest whats the issue with the layout?

Comment: Have you checked this one [How to use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31000081/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod I checked but none of the solutions are working...