# Unable to scroll RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have Problem : RecyclerView not scrolling.
Design : cover Image then RecyclerView with menu.
it show RecyclerView but I cant touch to go down in it just suck
I have tired to : Replace menu with RecyclerView but it make big problem
and setNestedScrollingEnabled Too.
any slove?

```Java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--    background Logo-->
    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/brown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/haneenrama"
        android:contentDescription="@string/name_offical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        ></ImageView>

    <!--    RecyclerView-->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<!--menu-->
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="end"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            ></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/NavigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemBackground="@color/rmade"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    ></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>





</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: do you really need the `NestedScrollView` ? It could be your problem , at least I had the same... Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: else, just try this in your `RecyclerView` : `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Can you post the picture to get a visual representation of your UI? Can you tell us whether you are scrolling on the Recyclerview items or on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved it.
 this is Cover RecyclerView

```
    <!--menu-->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
```

So I replace it To :

```
<!--menu-->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <!--    RecyclerView-->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing your `NestedScrollView` as it overlaps with `RecyclerView` and that's why it#s not scrolling.

Else you could insert that code in your `RecyclerCode`:

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

A more detailed answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000081/how-to-use-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview)

Comment: I did but no result.

Comment: @user113428 what exactly did you do? I listed 2 options

Comment: this two , I just removed NastedScrollView

Comment: could you share a picture of how it looks like? and maybe your RecyclerView initialization code @user113428

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `android:fillViewport="true"` in NestedScrollView Tag...
then add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in RecyclerView Tag...

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```