# CoordinatorLayout inside another CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

`CorodinatorLayout` inside another `CoordinatorLayout` such that scrolling the child-view should also scroll the Parent `CoordinatorLayout`.

I have a `coordinatorLayout` with `ViewPager` that contains different `Fragment` such that on `Scroll` will hide the `tabLayout`

I have another `coordinatorLayout` that has a `viewPager`. This `fragment` is inflated in `ViewPager` of parent fragment(parent `Coordinator layout`).

The problem is `onScrolling` the child fragment in `childViewpager` only reflects in `coordinator layout` of child `fragment` and not in the Parent `coordinator layout` that I need to do to hide the `tablayout`.

the structure is:

```
CoordinatorLayout(p) ->(tablayout(p) & ViewPager(p) -> CoordinatorLayout(c)  ->(tablayout(c) & ViewPAger(c) ->recyclerView(cc)))

p -> parent;

c -> child; cc -> child to child
```

How to make on scrolling recycler view will affect both **coordinator layout** so that the **toolbar tablayout(p)** will be get hides.

Comment: hope this can help better organize your code:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Comment: did you figure it out? I'm having the same exact issue

Comment: I am fixing the same issue. How do you solve it?

Answer (score 50):

I know it's an old question.
But I searched a long time to include an `CoordinatorLayout` in a fragment, which is in another `CoordinatorLayout`.

I modified the answer of dev.bmax a little bit to call both coordinator layouts and call the attached behaviors of both layouts.

So here is my solution.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class NestedCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild {

    private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int     nestedScrollAxes) {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        boolean tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(View target) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target);
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        int[][] tConsumed = new int[2][2];
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, tConsumed[0]);
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null);
        consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0];
        consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                           int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean tHandled = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY);
        return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        boolean tHandled = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
        return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
                                    int dyUnconsumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it, thanks. This code passes all scroll actions to both inner and outer CoordinatorLayout's at all times. One slight change I had to make to allow only inner one to keep consuming scroll until scrolled to top/bottom was this line in `onNestedPreScroll()`: `dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx - tConsumed[0][0], dy - tConsumed[0][1], tConsumed[1], null);`.

Comment: To let this work with Support lib v26, add overrides for onNestedPreScroll, onNestedScroll, onStopNestedScroll and onStartNestedScroll all with their type parameter. Also call the helper correct method with the type parameters in those methods.

Comment: Thx Marc. Your comment for sure saved me few hours. If someone need full example - will find it here:
https://snipsave.com/mateuszpryczkowski/#/snippet/OkfTpFB1f11zdKlH0o

Comment: this is working fine but both parent and child are hiding together. I want that child will hide first and then parent starts hiding on the scroll.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this should be in the support library. For some reason, the behavior was still slightly different from the one that is not nested, so I decided to inherit from `NestedScrollingChild2` like RecyclerView does. And now it works perfectly. Here is the final version of the `NestedCoordinatorLayout`: https://gist.github.com/Ghedeon/6f6be99e9960d3c225a4cd7731beee9e

Comment: AndroidX NestedCoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollingChild3 based on Mateusz Pryczkowski gist
https://gist.github.com/ReeMiXeR/97df5d8737380888893d107eccd27bcb

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple implementation of a nested coordinator layout.

```
/**
 * This variation of CoordinatorLayout also serves as a nested scrolling child,
 * which supports passing nested scrolling operations to it's parent when it's
 * own nested scrolling is locked.
 */
public class NestedCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild {

    private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;
    private volatile boolean mPassToParent;

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    /**
     * Locks the nested scrolling. Further scroll events will
     * be passed to the nested scrolling parent.
     */
    public void lockNestedScrolling() {
        mPassToParent = true;
    }

    /**
     * Unlocks the nested scrolling. Further scroll events will
     * be dispatched to this layout's own scrolling children.
     */
    public void unlockNestedScrolling() {
        mPassToParent = false;
    }

    /*
     * NestedScrollingParent implementation
     */

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes);
        /* Start tracking the current scroll */
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(View target) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target);
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        if (mPassToParent) {
            dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null);
        } else {
            super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                               int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        if (mPassToParent) {
            dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
        } else {
            super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (mPassToParent) {
            return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
        } else {
            return super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        if (mPassToParent) {
            return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
        } else {
            return super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
        }
    }

    /*
     * NestedScrollingChild implementation
     */

    @Override
    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
                                        int dyUnconsumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Kotlin Version** of NestedCoordinator Layout to use with multiple point scrollFlags for NestedCoordinatorLayouts based on [@fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343268/fabian) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660246/8743629).

The beHavior you will see is someThing like this:

[image]

And The **NestedCoordinatorLayout Implementation**:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
import androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChild
import androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper

class NestedCoordinatorLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : CoordinatorLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), NestedScrollingChild {

    private var mChildHelper: NestedScrollingChildHelper = NestedScrollingChildHelper(this)

    init {
        isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        target: View,
        dx: Int,
        dy: Int,
        consumed: IntArray,
        type: Int
    ) {
        val tConsumed = Array(2) { IntArray(2) }
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null)
        consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0]
        consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1]
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int
    ) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type)
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null)
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View, type: Int) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type)
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll()
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        val tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes, type)
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, nestedScrollAxes: Int): Boolean {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        val tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes)
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target)
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll()
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray) {
        val tConsumed = Array(2) { IntArray(2) }
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, tConsumed[0])
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null)
        consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0]
        consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1]
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int
    ) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed)
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreFling(
        target: View,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val tHandled = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY)
        return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || tHandled
    }

    override fun onNestedFling(
        target: View,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float,
        consumed: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        val tHandled = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed)
        return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || tHandled
    }

    override fun isNestedScrollingEnabled(): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled
    }

    override fun setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled = enabled
    }

    override fun startNestedScroll(axes: Int): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes)
    }

    override fun stopNestedScroll() {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll()
    }

    override fun hasNestedScrollingParent() = mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent()

    override fun dispatchNestedScroll(
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        offsetInWindow: IntArray?
    ): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(
            dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow
        )
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedPreScroll(
        dx: Int,
        dy: Int,
        consumed: IntArray?,
        offsetInWindow: IntArray?
    ): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow)
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedFling(
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float,
        consumed: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed)
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY)
    }
}
```

And your **XML** file Implementation is like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/firstScrollingToolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/chipsViewPager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/switchToolbar"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|snap|scroll">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/chipsTabLayout"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        </widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And This is a **Visual View** of implemented layout hierarchy:

[image]

This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) can give you a better view of how Android Views Hierarchy works actualy.

Comment: Definitely the better handling of the nested views and scroll events! Kudos!

Answer (score 5):

I made this a library, see it [on GitHub](https://github.com/natario1/NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout).

You just use `<NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout>` in your layout.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully, this will help others. The idea I implemented during preScroll calculates how much the parent is able to consume, if it is already 0, then call `super.onNestedPreScroll`.

Here's the code:

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChild2;
import android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild2 {

  private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;

  public NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
  }

  public NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
  }

  public NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
    return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
  }

  @Override
  public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
    return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent(int type) {
    return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent(type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int axes, int type) {
    boolean superResult = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes, type);
    return startNestedScroll(axes, type) || superResult;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    boolean superResult = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || superResult;
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null);
    if (consumed[1] == 0) {
      super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null);
    if (consumed[1] == 0) {
      super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
    dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null, type);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
    dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStopNestedScroll(View target, int type) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type);
    stopNestedScroll(type);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStopNestedScroll(View target) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(target);
    stopNestedScroll();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean superResult = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY);
    return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || superResult;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNestedFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    boolean superResult = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || superResult;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes, int type) {
    return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes, type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
    return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
  }

  @Override
  public void stopNestedScroll() {
    mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
  }

  @Override
  public void stopNestedScroll(int type) {
    mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll(type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow, type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, @Nullable int[] consumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, @Nullable int[] consumed, @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow, type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
  }
}
```

See also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kelvinc1024/b1419de9ad6bbcdbb68bad72ff58e069) on GithHub

Answer (score 2):

I have wrote one [ChildCoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/ToDou/nestrefresh/blob/master/nestrefresh/src/main/java/com/todou/nestrefresh/ChildCoordinatorLayout.kt) in my repo [nestrefresh](https://github.com/ToDou/nestrefresh).
In this repo, I wrap one AppBarLayout with ChildCoordinatorLayout and also add pull refresh for the ChildCoordinatorLayout with pull refresh behavior.
And dyUnConsumed give parent firstly then to the child.
This is the code:

```
class ChildCoordinatorLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : CoordinatorLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), NestedScrollingChild2 {

    private lateinit var childHelper: NestedScrollingChildHelper

    init {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        childHelper = NestedScrollingChildHelper(this)
        childHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
    }

    override fun setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        childHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled = enabled
    }

    override fun isNestedScrollingEnabled(): Boolean {
        return childHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled
    }

    override fun startNestedScroll(i: Int, i1: Int): Boolean {
        return childHelper.startNestedScroll(i, i1)
    }

    override fun stopNestedScroll(i: Int) {
        childHelper.stopNestedScroll(i)
    }

    override fun hasNestedScrollingParent(i: Int): Boolean {
        return childHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent()
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedScroll(i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int, ints: IntArray?, i4: Int): Boolean {
        return childHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(i, i1, i2, i3, ints, i4)
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedPreScroll(i: Int, i1: Int, ints: IntArray?, ints1: IntArray?, i2: Int): Boolean {
        return childHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(i, i1, ints, ints1, i2)
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        return childHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY)
    }

    override fun dispatchNestedFling(velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float, consumed: Boolean): Boolean {
        return childHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed)
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
        if (type == TYPE_TOUCH) {
            stopNestedScroll(TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
            ViewCompat.stopNestedScroll(child, TYPE_NON_TOUCH)
        }
        val handle = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes, type)
        return startNestedScroll(axes, type) || handle
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View, type: Int) {
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type)
        stopNestedScroll(type)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int) {
        val thisConsume = IntArray(2)
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, thisConsume, null, type)
        consumed[0] += thisConsume[0]
        consumed[1] += thisConsume[1]
        thisConsume[0] = 0
        thisConsume[1] = 0
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx - consumed[0], dy - consumed[1], thisConsume, type)
        consumed[0] += thisConsume[0]
        consumed[1] += thisConsume[1]

    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int
    ) {

        val offsetInWindow = IntArray(2)
        target.getLocationInWindow(offsetInWindow)
        val startX = offsetInWindow[0]
        val startY = offsetInWindow[1]
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type)
        target.getLocationInWindow(offsetInWindow)
        offsetInWindow[0] -= startX
        offsetInWindow[1] -= startY
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed + offsetInWindow[0]
            , dyUnconsumed + offsetInWindow[1], null, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreFling(target: View, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        val handled = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY)
        return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || handled
    }

    override fun onNestedFling(target: View, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float, consumed: Boolean): Boolean {
        val handled = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed)
        return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || handled
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported by `CoordinatorLayout`.

Check the code in `NestedScrollingChildHelper.startNestedScroll()` and `CoordinatorLayout.onStartNestedScroll()`, the nested scrolling event is "consumed" if one of `Behavior`s of your inner `CoordinatorLayout` consumes it, and won't be further propagated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom your CHILD CoordinatorLayout, let it implement NestedScrollingChild (ori coordinatorlayout didn't implement it) and override some functions to enable dispatching nested scroll event to your PARENT CoordinatorLayout.