# BottomNavigationView hides when scrolling up instead of down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-support-design

The new `BottomNavigationView` from support library v25.0.0 is supposed to hide when scrolling down, in order to see all the items from a list. However, in my testing scenario, the view hides when scrolling up. Any ideas what can cause this reverse behavior?

The `inner_fragment` is set up as a Fragment inserted inside the `activity_main_framelayout_content` Framelayout. XML layouts below:

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_coordinatorlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_appbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <include layout="@layout/activity_main_spinner_layout"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_framelayout_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_framelayout_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/color_black_700"/>
```

**inner_fragment.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_fragment_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/inner_fragment_bottom_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/inner_fragment"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bg_bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/ic_bottom_navigation"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/ic_bottom_navigation"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should put the BottomNavigationView as the direct child of CoordinatorLayout. Also from my try, i think behavior is not supported right now for BottomNavigationView, or you should implement your own custom behavior.

Comment: The behavior clearly works even if it isn't a direct child, as it would not scroll at all if it didn't. Even NestedScrollview's that aren't direct children of the CoordinatorLayout still work flawlessly, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: No, it isnt support app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: The BottomNavigationView responds to scroll events even without setting the scrollFlags. Setting the flags doesn't change anything.

Comment: How did you work around this @BogdanZurac? I have the exact same situation.

Comment: Listener on the AppBarLayout and moving the BottomNavigationView inside the main layout, as I recall.

Comment: Thank you @BogdanZurac, I will try implementing it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This release of **BottomNavigationView** is missing scrolling behavior to work out of the box as specified in the guidelines.

I [wrote an article on what's missing and how you can fix it](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottomnavigationview-missing-pearls-eaa950f9ad4e#.p1i01wwui). This includes implementing scrolling behavior of the **BottomNavigationView** in **CoordinatorLayout**.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be having any effect though. Bear in mind that the whole inner fragment is contained inside of a FrameLayout with appbar_scrolling_view_behavior.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. View that has the behavior must be direct descendant of the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Well yeah, but in this use case, it is contained inside of a Fragment that can be swapped with other fragments inside the main activity. So cannot do that effectively with the current navigation structure... However, how do you explain that the default behavior works without any changes whatsoever for the BottomNavigationView? Granted, in reverse compared to the Toolbar, but still. LE: I can confirm though that using it as a direct child of CoordinatorLayout works.

Answer (score 11):

A simple solution is to just add an offset listener to appbarlayout. Works perfectly for me.

So something like this:

```
((AppBarLayout)toolbar.getParent()).addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        mNavigationBar.setTranslationY(verticalOffset*-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works when the BottomNavigationView is inside the parent CoordinatorLayout, but it stops working altogether when you move the BottomNavigationView inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: By far the best solution I found

Comment: I wasted one full day to figure out what's the issue. You saved my time bro. Thanks for the solution. Best solution.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to replace the FrameLayout with a NestedCoordinatorLayout from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660246/2233621 and then add the BottomNavigationBehavior from  Nikola's blog post https://medium.com/@nullthemall/bottomnavigationview-missing-pearls-eaa950f9ad4e#.p1i01wwui that way your bottom navigation behaviour can listen for nested scrolling of the fragment inside the NestedCoordinatorLayout

I believe you could use another view that implements NestedScrollParent + NestedScrollChild for the same behaviour.