# RecyclerView + CoordinatorLayout + BottomSheet - RecyclerView does not scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

**Layout :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:expanded="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="36dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Sample text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Problem :**

When the bottom sheet is `EXPANDED`, the `RecyclerView` scrolling works fine. But when it is `COLLAPSED`, it is not possible to scroll to the bottom of the list. Some items are either cut off or not shown.

**Solutions tried :**

1. Tried setting `setAutoMeasureEnabled` to true for the `LayoutManager`.
2. Set `RecyclerView` height to `wrap_content`.
3. Put `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`.
4. Used [NestedCoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660246/1129612) as the root.

**Support Version :** 26.1.0

Can someone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: please specify support library version

Comment: You have malformed layout file. I see two CoordinatorLayout opening tags but only one is closed