# NestedScrollView inside NestedCoordinatorLayout sometimes stuck

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm using NestedCoordinatorLayout and I used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181372/coordinatorlayout-inside-another-coordinatorlayout).
The NestedCoordinatorLayout work prefect with RecyclerView as you can see at Figure 1.[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UcoS.gif).
The Problem is when I use NestedScrollView instead of RecyclerView, the NestedCoordinatorLayout is not listening to the gesture of the NestedScrollView, it sometimes get stuck I mean it does not pull the header as expected. But if I click on the screen is pulls the header (Figure 2)[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRCNJ.gif).

Layout with RecyclerView - work perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="centerMapVM"
            type="com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.fragments.centerMap.CenterMapFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.NestedCoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="334dp"
                android:minHeight="181dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mapFragment"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mapFragment"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="@{centerMapVM::onClickBtnLocation}"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_btn"
                        app:layout_anchor="@id/mapFragment"
                        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="@{centerMapVM::onClickBtnCentersFilter}"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_white_2_btn"
                        app:layout_anchor="@id/mapFragment"
                        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCenters"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape_top_corners"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.NestedCoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Layout with NestedScrollView - not work as ecpected

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="infoCenterVM"
            type="com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.fragments.infoCenter.InfoCenterFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.NestedCoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarContainerInfoCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_buttonsTemp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:minHeight="99dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentInfoCenter"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nesScroTemp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/some_text" />
            <!--TODO fix the nestedScroll-->
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </com.groupbci.www.costumerservice.views.NestedCoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Class NestedCoordinatorLayout

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class NestedCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout implements NestedScrollingChild {

    private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    public NestedCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
        int[][] tConsumed = new int[2][2];
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null);
        consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0];
        consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(View target, int type) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target, type);
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes, int type) {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        boolean tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes, type);
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        boolean tHandled = super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
        /* Enable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        return startNestedScroll(nestedScrollAxes) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(View target) {
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of our own children */
        super.onStopNestedScroll(target);
        /* Disable the scrolling behavior of the parent's other children  */
        stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        int[][] tConsumed = new int[2][2];
        super.onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, tConsumed[0]);
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, tConsumed[1], null);
        consumed[0] = tConsumed[0][0] + tConsumed[1][0];
        consumed[1] = tConsumed[0][1] + tConsumed[1][1];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
                               int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean tHandled = super.onNestedPreFling(target, velocityX, velocityY);
        return dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        boolean tHandled = super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
        return dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed) || tHandled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed,
                                        int dyUnconsumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                dyUnconsumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is was faster, I found the answer.
The problem that exists in NestedScrollView and not in RecyclerView it Fling.
So I used in [this](https://github.com/Dimezis/FlingableNestedScrollView/blob/master/FlingableNestedScrollView.java)