# How to add separator at particular position inside recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, list-separator

I have a list of taskLists. To show the list I have used recyclerview. I have 1st 3 items as today , tomorrow and later in my list. I want to add one separator after 1st 3 items in recycler view. How can I do this?

Adapter :

```
    public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<ListData> item;
    public static final int TYPE1=1;
    Context conext;


  public   ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> item) {
        this.conext=context;
        this.item=item;

    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ListData listData);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return item.size();

    }
    public void remove(int position) {
        item.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

   // @Override
   // public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       // return item.get(position).getExpenseType();// Assume that this return 1 0r 2
  //  }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder,final int i) {

        itemViewHolder.listName.setText(item.get(i).getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.list_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView,viewType);

    }


    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView listName;


        ItemViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);

            listName  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listData);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help with this how can I put separator after 3 items in list? 
Thank you..

Comment: can you share the screenshot that you want to achieve

Comment: http://android.amberfog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/004.png  ......like this. after 3 items. @PhanVănLinh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is define 2 types of RecyclerView rows (one for normal row and one for separator)
Another solution is you should a `Separator View` in the bottom of your `custom RecycleView row xml`

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/separatorView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:visible="gone"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Then in `bindViewHolder` of your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, hide the separator in normal row and visible it in separator row

```
 @Override
    public void bindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(position == separatorPosition){
           holder.separatorView.visible = View.VISIBLE;
        }else{
           holder.separatorView.visible = View.GONE;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: simplest one.. Thank you..@Phan Văn Linh

Comment: but in the future if your separator view is more complex, i suggest that you should use solution 1 (define 2 types of RecyclerView). happy coding

Comment: No I only wanted this way.. :-) Thank you..@Phan Văn Linh

Comment: I planned to set the static relativelayout in 0th position of adapter.But my webservices images were loading from 0th position.So I can't set the static relativelayout in adapter at 0th position.can you please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192034/recyclerview-inside-nested-scroll-view-loading-all-datas-instead-of-calling-one).

Answer (score 4):

You should define 2 types of RecyclerView rows:

```
...YourRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>

public static final int COMMON = 1;
public static final int SEPARATOR = 2;
```

Override `getItemViewType` method of your `Adapter`:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position%10 == 0) //each 10 row is separator (change it!)
        return SEPARATOR;
    else return COMMON;
}
```

Change `onCreateViewHolder` method of your `Adapter`:

```
@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == COMMON)
        return new ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false));
    else
        return new SeparatorHolder(LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.separator_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
     if (getItemViewType(position) == COMMON) {
          //do stuff
     } else {
     }
}
```

---

`ItemViewHolder` extends `BaseViewHolder`
`SeparatorHolder` extends `BaseViewHolder`
`BaseViewHolder` extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Comment: But I want to display the whole list won't it check for the view type if we have put a condition?@Vladimir Kulyk

Comment: @Sid anyway, it is correct way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two `ViewHolder` class and Switch them in `onCreateViewHolder`. One containing your custom line, and others as your custom list items.

```
   class ViewHolderLine extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { //contains line
    }

    class ViewHolderItems extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { //contains data
    }

  @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return item.get(position).getExpenseType();// Assume that this return 1 0r 2
   }

  @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int viewType) {

       switch (viewType) {
         case 1: return new ViewHolderLine();
         case 2:
             View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.list_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(itemView,viewType);
         }


  }
```

You can see the details description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

if you know that you are only going to add separator in the 1st three items, then you can put a condition based on the `position` of the item, inside `onBindViewHolder`.

ps: Please do not forget to add an else block after an if block

Answer (score 1):

I have a recyclerview with section header and variable number of items in each section. The section should have a line separator across entire screen. and items must have a padded line between them. 
[image]
So, my solution(in kotlin) was having two viewholders, one for header and one for item. in getItemViewType, return the type based on the item.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    if(dataList[position] is HeaderItem)
        return Companion.TYPE_HEADER
    return Companion.TYPE_ITEM
   }
```

and create the corresponding viewholder in createviewholder, bind accordingly.

Used

> parent.getChildViewHolder(parent.getChildAt(i))

to decide the padding(or color or width) for the item separator.

```
class ItemDivider(context: Context) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    private var mDivider: Drawable
    private val mContext = context
companion object {
    private val ATTRS = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.listDivider)
}

init {
    val styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS)
    mDivider = styledAttributes.getDrawable(0)
    mDivider.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, <color>))
    styledAttributes.recycle()
}

override fun onDraw(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
    val right = parent.width - parent.paddingRight

    for (i in 0 until parent.childCount - 1) {
        val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
        val params = child.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val left = if (parent.getChildViewHolder(child) is HeaderViewHolder) {
            0
        } else {
            child.left + params.leftMargin + mContext.resources.getDimension(<padding_in_dp>).toInt()
        }
        val top = child.bottom + params.bottomMargin
        val bottom = top + mDivider.intrinsicHeight + <divider_height>

        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
        mDivider.draw(c)
    }
}
}
```

remember to replace the color, padding, divider height with valid values.

Hope it helps!