# Unable to hide toolbar when recyclerview is scrolled using Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using the below code in my Fragment. The Toolbar hides when I scroll the appbarlayout, how ever when I scroll recyclerview it doesn't hide. What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbars"
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lv_nearby"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatbutton_nearby"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/filter" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code for custom_tooolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_nearby"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

</GridView>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Try without "<include>" it may be work.

Comment: @aksacha tried, doesn't work

Comment: whats your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: My targetSdkVersion is 19

Comment: Update targetSdk as 23 then check.

Comment: please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40182035/3960700)

Answer (score 7):

You need to put you `RecycleView` in `NestedScrollView` and set the layout behavior to `NestedScrollView` in separate layout and include in the main layout like this

**content_scrolling.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lv_nearby"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Your Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbars"
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   //Include your scroll layout here
   <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatbutton_nearby"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/filter" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After that set nested scrolling for `RecycleView` as false like this:

```
yourrecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I implemented  and its working fine please check this:
our xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/message_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and item for ReclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

then AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior Class which used in AppbarLayout:

```
public class AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

private ValueAnimator mAnimator;
private boolean mNestedScrollStarted = false;

public AppBarLayoutSnapBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                                   View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    mNestedScrollStarted = super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    if (mNestedScrollStarted && mAnimator != null) {
        mAnimator.cancel();
    }
    return mNestedScrollStarted;
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);

    if (!mNestedScrollStarted) {
        return;
    }

    mNestedScrollStarted = false;

    int scrollRange = child.getTotalScrollRange();
    int topOffset = getTopAndBottomOffset();

    if (topOffset <= -scrollRange || topOffset >= 0) {
        // Already fully visible or fully invisible
        return;
    }

    if (topOffset < -(scrollRange / 2f)) {
        // Snap up (to fully invisible)
        animateOffsetTo(-scrollRange);
    } else {
        // Snap down (to fully visible)
        animateOffsetTo(0);
    }
}

private void animateOffsetTo(int offset) {
    if (mAnimator == null) {
        mAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        mAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        mAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                setTopAndBottomOffset((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
    } else {
        mAnimator.cancel();
    }

    mAnimator.setIntValues(getTopAndBottomOffset(), offset);
    mAnimator.start();
}
```

and our Activity class with adapter:

```
public class Second extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(createItemList(), this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}


private ArrayList<String> createItemList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        list.add(new String("List Item " + i));
    }
    return list;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {
    private  String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    public  MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String>list, Context context)
    {
        this.mDataset=list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public  class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }



    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

 }
```

}
try this may be it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add FitSystemWindows to both Coordinator Layout and AppbarLayout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Hope it helps:

Comment: remove this attribute : app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" from toolbar

Comment: It is necessary for the scroll to work. Anyway I tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work as well. Strange thing is when I scroll the toolbar, it works fine, but when I scroll recyclerview it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are right, **It does not hide the `Toolbar` when scrolling the `RecyclerView`.**

I've test the code and now, It's working by deleting `Include`, Adding `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to both `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout`, Also, Some fixes.

**Here is the code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid_nearby"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="4"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lv_nearby"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatbutton_nearby"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you code is fine.just upgrade you gradle build version to newer one it will work properly. I have tested this code in

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

target version `targetSdkVersion 25`

and design lib `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'` and its woking properly.