# Recyclerview with CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Based on the comments below I have changed my `layout`. It is working but when I go to the bottom of items in `recyclerview` and try to scroll up, it only goes up to the start of the `recyclerview`. I have to scroll again  to get to the `header`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_profile"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ap_placeholder"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/profile_name"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_profile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/username"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_profile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_profile_name"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/settings_content_description"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ap_settings"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@string/profile_description"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_profile_description"/>

            <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
                android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/ap_yellow"
                app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/ap_black"
                app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/profile_bar_tabs"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_followers"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_history"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:text="@string/tv_history"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number_history"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_followers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tv_followers"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_history"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tv_following"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number_followers"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_following"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:text="@string/tv_following"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number_following"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number_history"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/test_history"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_history"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_history"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number_followers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/test_followers"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/number_history"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/number_following"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number_following"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/test_following"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_following"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_following"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"/>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: As per my recommendation, initialize new adapter object with required layout on the click of button.

Comment: @RahulSharma but then how would I still have the `header`?

Comment: add required header to new adapter as you are doing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

If you need exact instagram design, please check out this [Sample](https://github.com/frogermcs/InstaMaterial):

When you click on the tab button, just use hide and show view and put separate layout manager for both.

```
 private boolean gridClick = false;


   case R.id.list_click:                       

                if(listClick) {                 // Check whether the tab is already clicked or not

                    Log.e("AlreadyClicked", "Test");

                } else {

                    Log.e("ClickedFirstTime", "Test");

                    loadPost();

                    ivGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);      // Hiding grid recyclerview
                    ivList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   // showing list recyclerview

                    rvGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);      // Make grid recyclerview as gone
                    recyclerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // make listview as visible



                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);       // Use separate layoutmanager for list recyclerview

                    recyclerList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerList.setAdapter(friendsProfileUserPostitemsAdapter);

                    listClick = true;


                }

                break;
```

Comment: Hmm I can't access those lists because they are in different binders. I need to hide/show items from the second binder in the first one according to your solution.

Comment: @Esteban I have already did instagram designs.You can simply do with 4 or 5 buttons in single activity.Just hide and show the views according to that.You need to user Coordinator layout like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40182035/3960700).Never use nested scroll view .Its bad way to do in recyclerview.

Comment: @Esteban check my edited post.When you run that sample, you can get some clear identification.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, even though the scrolling is not smooth here either. You can't get to top with a fling. :(

Comment: @Esteban are you facing any issues now?

Comment: When I scroll down in the `recyclerview` and I fling back to top, I only get to the top of the `recyclerview`. I need to scroll once more to get to the header (which is the `AppBarLayout`).

Comment: @Esteban I think in that sample also they did like that only it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done wrong implementation. Dont need to add TabLayout in RecyclerView item.

You code should be like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
          <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

              <YourHeaderLayout />
              <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />              

          </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView /> 
    <!-- OR -->
    <ViewPager />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here If you display `RecyclerView` then you **need to change LayoutManager on Tab press.** Or you can place two `RecyclerView` with List and Grid in `ViewPager`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having the `CollapsingToolbarLayout?` I need the content to be scroll-able, something like Instagram user profile page.

Comment: You can use AppBarLayout without CollapsingToolbarLayout. And for scrolling you can you android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.

Comment: @Esteban doesn't getting.What you want to say about header scrolling?

Comment: When I scroll to bottom and then I fling to top I only get to the top of the `recyclerview`, but not the whole layout. I've found some workaround but it does not really solve the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Esteban You are saying that when to scroll to top your header layout is visible. right?